# what does this hyphen do between columns in order by clause in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sql-order-by

what does this **hyphen** do **between updated_at and created_at** columns in order by clause ?

```
select * from `users` order by updated_at - created_at DESC
```

Comment: - is minus in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a minus sign, so it subtracts the created date from the updated date on each row and uses the result for ordering the rows that are returned.

The are both timestamps, with the created date coming first and thus being a lower number. The greater the difference between the created date and updated date the higher up in the results it will be using a descending order, with results that have the same updated and created date coming last.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the intent of the `order by` clause is to sort by the difference between the two dates. The rows where the difference is the greatest are sorted first.

However, *if* the columns are actually of a `date`-like datatype, this is not likley to work properly in MySQL, that treats date substractions in a counter-intuitive and unreliable manner (under the hood, dates are implicitly conveted to integer values).

You should be using date functions instead, for example:

```
order by unix_timestamp(updated_at) - unix_timestamp(created_at) desc
```

Or:

```
order by timestampdiff(second, created_at, updated_at) desc
```